# Cannot enable debugger for Nodejs VSCODE

Tags: node.js

This is my first time trying to setup Nodejs with debugger tool. My lauch.json code is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run the debugger in VS code and go to debug console. I get:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=29182 app.js
>   Debugger
>   listening on ws://127.0.0.1:29182/c2a39cf7-ab13-4sd1b-afs5-eb9wqwq5de9

I have setup a breakpoint on my app.js as well.

I have tried to go to the

```
ws://127.0.0.1:29182/c2a39cf7-ab13-4sd1b-afs5-eb9wqwq5de9
```

url as shown in the debugger but it give me:

> Site cannot be reached

error in chrome

Answer (score 0):

No this is the port where debugger is listening you are not supposed to go to that path,you will go to your port where your nodejs server is listening and debugger will listen to that.

For Example:
I have a node server running on port 3000 and I have a get request like this

```
app.get('/',()=>{
   console.log("This is get request");
 })
```

and I have a break point on this line: `console.log("This is get request");`. I will start server by running debugger.

Then I will go to localhost:3000 from postman to check and debugger will called automatically.